Assign static ip to an ubuntu image in docker
I currently have a test environment to implement a reverse proxy server, I have Docker Desktop installed on Windows 10, I have a test container running and in that container an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS image and I need to configure a static IP into Ubuntu image to configure OpenVPN and squid.
I investigated the change with the netplan command but it is not installed into Ubuntu image and when I try to install it it sends me this message:
Package netplan is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsolete, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'netplan' has no installation candidate

Many of the commands always send me this type of message
bash: command not found

So what package or tool do I need to change the network configuration? again all this into the Ubuntu image.

It is not clear what you are asking. docker containers have their own virtual network and IP addresses running in a different subnet than your Windows host. Do you want to assign a static IP in the docker virtual network or in your home/office network? Typically you use the IP address of the host computer (your Windows computer) and port forwarding to access the docker container. Add all the additional information including why you need a static IP address for which packages.. Edit your question and all the extra information in your question.

Ok, I added more information to see if it was clear, I will pay attention to your comment

You may find this YouTube video useful. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu and everything to do with Docker.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a Docker networking question, not a Ubuntu question.

This is a docker question not an ubuntu question. Sounds like you are trying to edit the container directly. That isn't what you want to do. You have to assign it an IP from container creation like this:

docker run --net customnetwork --ip 172.20.0.10 -d container

Review docker's documentation or I found this link which might help you out a bit more.
